# Load file on launch of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

I know that when you close a project inside Visual Studio, the last file that you had open will be opened when you reopen the same project.  I am wondering if this is an setting that I can use to always open a specific file when a project is launched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some research and testing I found out that what I want to do is not possible.  The SUO file that is created by Visual Studio holds the information of the last file opened and there is no setting or property that I can use that will allow me to have this written into the project file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your shortcut to devenv.exe and pass the [file name as the first argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
, however if the first argument is a file that is not a solution or project, that file will open in the appropriate editor, in a new instance of the IDE.

Comment: that wont help because what I need is for Visual Studio to still launch but to have my file in question open even if it was not the last file open when the project was closed.

Comment: It will still launch, the first argument is the file path regardless of what solution/project was opened last.

Comment: ok, I think I need to explain this a little better.  I need to see if there is a setting in VS that will let me do this because it is going to be a distributed sample and I cannot alter each devenv.exe for each customer I have.  If I am missing something then please let me know.